Rendering SSRS outputs
This is a SSRS report rendering question but unsure which way to go with it.
If I have an SSRS report with no parameters I can add to the command line &rs:Format=WORD&rs:Command=Render (or WORDOPENXML) and the report will auto create in Word but it will save to the downloads folder.  In Edge you can change the download settings for "ask me what to do with each download" therefore the user will be prompted to open the document but that's annoying.
Is there any way possible that the report will generate and then open directly in word eliminating the need to fetch the file from a folder?
thanks in advance
